# Dynamic programming problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

our uni is closed because of the COVID-19 and I'm trying to homelearn dynamic programming.

In our algorithms book, there is the following problem: (an example problem for dynamic programming)

> A driver has 3 cars. He wants to use all of the 3 cars, but want to
>   use the least gas. Each car has a different engine, so it will consume
>   different amounts of gas to get to each destination. What is the least amount of gas
>   we can consume while still using each car? After he switches cars, he
>   can't go back to the previous car.
>
> Input description:
>
> First is a number $n$, which is the number of destinations that he
>   wants to reach.  Then there are 3 lines, each is the gas consumed
>   while trying to reach each destination (line 1 is car 1, line 2 is car
>   2, etc..)
>
> Example input:
>
> 7
>
> 2 4 1 5 1 1 2
>
> 3 3 2 5 3 2 2
>
> 1 1 5 4 3 3 3
>
> Example output:
>
> 12 (third car (2 destinations), first car (4 destinations), second car (1 destination).)

However, I can't figure out how to start, as I'm still learning DP. Could you please help me or give me any hints?

I think it's a great good example problem, because other problems are very similar so if I master this one, I should be able to solve other problems.

Thanks!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: Great good cross-post of [Dynamic programming - finding the least amount of gas consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60745506/3789665).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60746558/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/121882/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(i,j)$ be the gas consumed when travelling to destination $i$ with car $j$.

Guess the optimal order $\langle c_1, c_2, c_3 \rangle$ of cars (there are only $3! = 6$ possible permutations).

Define $OPT[i,j]$ as the minimum amount of gas needed for reaching the first $i$ destinations using cars $c_1, \dots, c_j$ in this order, with the constraint that each car must be used at least once. If no feasible solution exists then $OPT[i,j] = + \infty$.

According to the above definition, you have $$OPT[1,j] = \begin{cases}
g(1, c_1) & \mbox{if } j=1 \\
+\infty & \mbox{if } j>1
\end{cases}$$.

and, for $i=2, \dots, n$:

$$OPT[i,j] = g(i,c_j)+
\begin{cases}
OPT[i-1, j] & \mbox{if } j=1 \\
\min\{ OPT[i-1, j], OPT[i-1, j-1] \} & \mbox{if } j>1
\end{cases}.$$

The solution to your problem is $OPT[n,3]$, which can be computed in $O(n)$ time using dynamic programming.

Comment: How does it ensure that all cars have to be used?

Comment: By definition of $OPT[n,3]$, the last car used must be $c_3$. Moreover, the first car used must necessarily be $c_1$ (since $OPT[1,j]$ is finite iff $j=1$). Finally, notice that if car $c_j$ is used to travel to the $i$-th city (with $i>1$), then the formulas ensure that car used to reach the $(i-1)$-th city is either $c_j$ or $c_{j-1}$ (if $j>1$). This means that a solution cannot use $c_1$ immediately before $c_3$, i.e., $c_2$ must be used as well.

Comment: So you are imposing an order of cars to be 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: No, I am imposing that the order of cars is $c_1, c_2, c_3$, which is some permutation of $1,2,3$.

Comment: for each permutation , you need to run the same equations right? I mean for .e.g. c1 = 1, c2= 2, c3 = 3 and then c1 = 1, c2 = 3, c3 = 2 then c1 = 2, c2 = 1, c3 = 3 etc. right?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to run this dynamic programming algorithm for all $6$ permutations of $1,2,3$.

Comment: OK got it! Good.